# Google Play Console // App Analyitcs Daily Active Users // Opt-In

Tags: android, google-play, analytics, google-play-console

I'm search for an explanation of the Opt-In Rate in Google Play Console for Daily and Monthly Active Users. In Apple Connect there is a hint "Only Opt-In". Apple says approx. 30% of all users gav their opt-in.

In Google Play Console I can't find anything regarding this topic.

Can somebody help?

And another question is:
In some of my Apps, I can't see any numbers for DAUs and MAUs. There are a lot of installations and it's 100% sure, that someone has used the App, but there is "No Data Available"
And I can't see any issue with this Apps.

Kind regards,
Sam

Comment: Same question here. Got any updates?